# Perl code to check progress bar level and display through jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, perl

I have a Perl code which retrieves the percentage of a usage which is 30%. I have written HTML which has class progressbar and value in perl as $usage. And I have used that class in jQuery to show the progress bar in a page. But its not working.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>

$(function() {
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar( "value" );
});
</script>

<div class="progressbar" value=<% $usage_percentage %></div>

<%perl>
my $usage_percentage = 30;
</%perl>
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You use `$usage` in one place and `$usage_percentage` in another.

Comment: Thanks...Correction done

Comment: Am I correct that you're using Mason? If so, you should add the [tag:mason] tag to your question, since there are a number of different Perl templating solutions that use similar delimiters.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your code. First, you use the ID selector `$("#progressbar")` but nothing in your HTML has that ID. Change

```html
<div class="progressbar" ... >
```

to

```html
<div id="progressbar" ... >
```

Second, `value` is not a valid attribute for `<div>` tags. When passing data from Perl to HTML/JavaScript, I would recommend using [HTML5 `data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes), e.g.

```html
<div id="progressbar" data-percent-used="30"></div>
```

jQuery provides a [convenient method](http://api.jquery.com/data/) for accessing `data-*` attributes:

```js
var percentUsed = $( "#progressbar" ).data( "percent-used" ); // 30
```

Note that you can still use `data-*` attributes in HTML4, they are simply treated as regular attributes.

Third, you're calling a method to [get the value](http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/#method-value) of the progress bar, not set it. Change

```js
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar( "value" );`
```

to

```js
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({ value: 30 });
```

to set the value to 30, for example.

Putting it all together:

```js
<script>
    $(function() {
        var container = $( "#progressbar" );
        container.progressbar({ value: container.data( "percent-used" ) });
    });
</script>

<div id="progressbar" data-percent-used="<% $usage_percentage %>"></div>
```

Comment: I want to call the $usage_percentage directly to jQuery progress bar through HTML id or class. Isnt that possible?

Comment: How to do this without the help of <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>?

Comment: What do you mean? I omitted those bits since you don't need to change them. Or are you saying you don't want to use jQuery?

Comment: No. Not that. I want to use jQuery. But I dont want to use these 2 lines <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: Well, if you want to use jQuery, you have to load it into your script *somehow*, and unless you want to copy paste the entire jQuery source directly into your script (which is a Really Bad Idea™), that's your best bet. Why don't you want those two lines?

Comment: I just wanted to know whether its possible to code without those 2 lines.

Comment: If yes, how is the question?

Comment: No, it's not possible to use jQuery without *loading* jQuery. You haven't answered *why* you want to do that, though.

Comment: Then its fine. No problem. Thanks. I dont have any answer